# Learning DirectX10 with GeForce7

Tags: directx

So I am planning to start learning DirectX by grabbing Frank Luna's book "Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 10". But since I have a GeForce Go 7 graphics card, I am wondering will I be able to at least test the code from the book? Or should I take his older book about DirectX 9, which my GPU supports? But speaking about that, it would be a little pity to learn outdated stuff since I read that DX10 has introduced quite a lot of new concept, so I am totally confused at the moment.

On the other hand, perhaps with the hardware I have I would be more happier learning older version of OpenGL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have the money to get updated hardware, get the book to match the hardware you have.

Most of what you will need to learn transfers from one to version to the other - if you get proficient with one version, you can move to another and keep most of your knowledge - because most of what you need for graphics programming isn't the API.

You just need to get started and get some code running as quick as possible!

Comment: Thanks for advice, xaxxon. So in the end I got OpenGL red book 5th edition, which covers version 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows 7 you *could* use [WARP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd285359.aspx) until you can get a hold of better hardware, but it will be *much* slower than using an actual DirectX 10 graphics card.

Comment: Is it the same thing used when executing the samples from SDK? I can launch DX10/11 samples with GF Go 7, but even a spinning cube doesn't give more then 20 FPMinute.